Try-Catch not working as expected with Drive Service
I have a Google App Script with this try-catch below. The script is return a 302 html stating
<!-- GSE Default Error --><H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>The document has moved.

How can I fix my code to catch the error. The issue is that someone else owns the file and I cannot delete it so, it is getting Moved Temporarily
try {
  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);
} catch (error) {
  Logger.log("error: " + error.message);
}

I was expecting to log the error and not throw html back.
(see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#settrashedtrashed)

are you sure that the error is not logged additionally?

Your [mcve] does not reproduce any problem for me

I found the issue was with Power Automate HTTP not handling a 302 redirect.
https://www.expiscornovus.com/2021/01/08/how-to-workaround-a-http-301/

This is far from answering what is being asked on this question: The question doesn't mention Power Automate, it's about a platform from a different digital services provider.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
